# Set VM IP via vagrant

Tags: ruby, vagrant, wildfly, vagrantfile

Is it possible to declare a static text IP in vagrant?

So far I am using this:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.network "public_network", ip: "192.168.1.111"
  end
```

I am looking for something like

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.network "public_network", ip: "testVM"
  end
```

I want to access my `Wildfly-Server` (running on the `VM`) with testVM:8080

Thanks for any help in advance

Answer (score 2):

`testVM` is not an IP so you cannot use that as the `ip` parameter.

You can set your host file to redirect the specific ip to your test domain, so you can add this line in your `/etc/hosts` file on your host

```
192.168.1.111    testVM.local
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! I already tried this and it worked.
But i would like to avoid this method, if its possible.
If i want to reach the Wildfly-Server from my host pc (on testVM:8080), i also have to configure the hosts file in windows.

Comment: it is not possible, if you dont configure your windows/mac hosts file, your host has no possibility to know about testVM and how to access it

Comment: if you dont want to set the file yourself, you can use some plugin to do this automatically (I believe https://github.com/cogitatio/vagrant-hostsupdater works with windows, otherwise, look in github I am sure there's a plugin to do this)